# Recommend a todo task service that can sync to Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, to-do, tasks

Is there a ToDo/Tasks service that can sync to windows mobile tasks, so they are accessible offline?

Today I learned I can sync Google calendar to winmo calendar, but not tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Google is notorious for not providing an API for tasks (I encourage you to read the funny comments on [this funny thread](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=987)).

Try [RememberTheMilk.com](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) - it provides [Outlook integration](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/milksync/outlook/) - and would therefore sync with WinMo.

Answer (score 0):

[Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/) is *excellent*! I've tried tens of different task management applications and web services, but this is the first one I'm *really* satisfied with. I use it actively every day, both for private business and at work. I don't know if it syncs with Windows Mobile, however, they do support a number of different [export/import and synchronization services](http://www.toodledo.com/connections.php) - perhaps one of them can work for you.

Comment: It seems it can export/import to Outlook, may be worth a while. Thanks. I very keen on trying their tool for procrastinators.